# How can I send two event parameter in one single Custom Dimension Google Analytics

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, analytics

[image]I want to pass two or more event parameters in a single custom dimension so that I can filter my data accordingly. Is there any way to do that? I have defined a custom event which have some parameters but in custom definition I can't send more than one parameter. Is there a way to send custom event parameters so that I can see event parameters on report.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very elegant, but you can modify an event through the event modification UI in Config -> Events -> Modify event

There, you can concat various values into an event and then use it for a CD.

However, you definitely can populate a new event through GTM and concatenate data in it however you wish. The GTM would be a more elegant solution since logic like that is meant to live in GTM, so then it's easier managed later on when nobody remembers how the CD was constructed.

Comment: I want my custom parameters on custom definition. The modify event suggests default parameters on analytics. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Fahmida firebase just suggest you to understand the logic. you can pass your custom parameters also.